# Is it possible to get Image from UIImageView after image is downloaded asynchronously using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, uiimageview, afnetworking

My code is

`[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"…"]];`

to set image. Which is working fine.

Now i want to know how can i get the downloaded image from imageView. If i do `imageView.image` I am ending up with placeholder image. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: NSString *ImageURL = @"YourURLHere";
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

Comment: What do you want to do with the image? You could save it as NSData to the disk and load it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use the following method:

```
[imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
      placeholderImage:placeholder
               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                   // the downloaded image is image
               } 
               failure:errorHandler]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another  method in that extension class

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure;
```

which gives you the image in success